# Moving values from one screen to another ERROR: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.message')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, native

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another in react native by carrying a value from one screen to the other however, i am getting the above error.  Ideally i would like send the value from within a flatlist, i am trying to achieve a clickable flatlist which carrys a parameter from the selected row to the other screen.

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

const ComponentsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  //example for detail scree
  return (
    <View>
    <FlatList
           data={[
             { key: 'Task 1' },
             { key: 'Task 2' },
             { key: 'Task 3' },
             { key: 'Task 4' },
             { key: 'Task 5' },
           ]}
           renderItem={({ item }) => {
               return (
                 <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() =>
                        navigation.navigate('Next', { message: 'hello from screen 1' })}
                 >
                      <Text >{item.key}</Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
               );
             }
           }

    />

    <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NextScreen')}
        title="Go to ImageScreen"
    />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
textStyle: {
  fontSize: 30
}
});

export default ComponentsScreen;
```

//NextScreen.js

```
  import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

//example for detail screen
const NextScreen = (route) => {
const { message } = route.params;

    return (
        <View>
          <Text>message: {JSON.stringify(message)}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default NextScreen;
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Index from './screens/Index';
import NextScreen from './screens/NextScreen';


const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Index,
  Next: NextScreen
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'App'
  }
}
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to receive a param for one screen to another you need to use the `getparam` function, for example: `const message = navigation.getParam('message');`

Comment: Hi hlebon, thanks for the response, i have tried  `const message = navigation.getParam('message', 'default');` and `const message = this.props.navigation.getParam('message', 'default');` and still getting no joy

Comment: Hi, what version of react-navigation are you using? 
I see in your NextScreen you are using `const NextScreen = (route) => {... }`. Be sure to destructure the props parameter `const NextScreen = ({ navigation }) => {... }`

Comment: Hi hlebon, yes that was the issue, i changed that it is now working.

Comment: still getting error, navigation.getParam() is undefined. I am usign. RN 5

Comment: this doesn't work now ...

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the way for moving values between Routes

```
 navigation.navigate('RouteB', {
        screen: 'ScreenC',
        params: { param1: "foo", param2: "bar" }
      })
```

Then you can take this values in `ScreenC` with

```
const ScreenC = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { param1, param2 } = route.params
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with 
encodeURIComponent(this.props.navigation.getParam('message');
or
encodeURIComponent(this.props.navigation.Param('message');

Answer (score 0):

```
 onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("RestaurantDetail", {
                        name: restaurant.name,
                        price: restaurant.price,
                        rating: restaurant.rating,
                        categories: restaurant.categories,
                        image: restaurant.image_url,
                        reviews: restaurant.reviews
                    })
                }}
```

pass it like this

```
const About = ({ route }) => {
const { name, image, categories, price, reviews, rating } = route.params;}
```

u can destruct it like this