# How do I pass the selected value in the drop down picker to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried to pass the data that is selected in the drop down picker to another page via https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C01CJlu7Q-I

First page

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'Japanese', value: 'J'},                  
             {label: 'Korean', value: 'K'},
             {label: 'Western', value: 'F'},
             {label:'Indonesian', value:'I'},
             {label: 'Taiwan', value: 'T'},
             {label:'Chinese', value:'C'},
            ]);
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
  
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text>What cusine would you like to eat today?</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SubScreen1", {paramKey:items})}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}
```

Another page where I am trying to pass the value to. Currently it is very simple but it cannot work

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const SubScreen1 = (route) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{route.params.paramkey}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen1

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

My app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import ForgetPasswordScreen from './screens/ForgetPasswordScreen';
import SubScreen1 from './screens/SubScreen1';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options= {{ headerShown : false }} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Forget Password" component={ForgetPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SubScreen1" component={SubScreen1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But when i clicked the search button, it is not jumping to the next page. I assume its something wrong with the passing of the key. How do i fix this?

After editing, I encountered another error. This happens after I press the search button. How do i solve this?

[image]

I tried referring to this [Moving values from one screen to another ERROR: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.message')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213758/moving-values-from-one-screen-to-another-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-eval) but it doesnt work

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const SubScreen1 = (route) => {
  const { param1 } = route.params.paramKey
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{param1}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen1

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Comment: You are passing `items` which is an array of drop down options, is this what you want? Or you should pass `value`?

Comment: I am trying to pass the selected value from the drop down picker to pass to another page in order to search the database with the value

Comment: Then you should use `navigation.navigate("Sub-Screen1", {paramkey: value})`. Please be aware your page name should be "Sub-Screen1" but not "SubScreen1".

Comment: Thanks for spotting my mistake. The issue is solved already.

Answer (score 0):

first log the value and see the response. you forgot the key of **items...**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const SubScreen1 = (route) => {
  const { param1 } = route.params.paramKey
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{param1.items}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen1

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```